# Need help in dealing with messages from Solve and Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, homework

I have a two part question,

I am trying to solve what should be a very straightforward equation, but I keep getting messages. Here is the equation

```
a = -0.0154213 Sin[Pi/4 + Pi/8*x]
```

Here is the code I am using

```
Solve[a == 0, x]
```

When I use this code, Mathematica tells me I should use `Reduce` for a complete solution.  When I use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`, I get "unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients".

Also, I want to solve the same equation for values between -2 and 2, How do I explicitly define that range? I tried using the following code to no avail.

```
Solve[a == 0, t, {-2, 2}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

FWIW, when i use `Solve` it does give me one of the three solutions I should be getting.

Comment: try `Solve[{a==0, -2<=t<=2},t]`

Comment: @kglr, you are awesome! thank you! Now, I got all 3 solutions I needed but they  came with the same, "unable to solve the system with inexact coefficient" error. Should I be worried about this error message? is it because its a periodic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `0.0154213` with the exact number `154213/10000000`:

```
a = -154213 /10000000 Sin[Pi/4 + Pi/8*x];

Solve[a == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[-((2 (π - 8 π C[1]))/π), 
>       C[1] ∈ Integers]},
>    {x -> ConditionalExpression[-((
>        2 (π - 4 (π + 2 π C[1])))/π), 
>       C[1] ∈ Integers]}}

```
Solve[a == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 0
```

> {{x -> -2}, {x -> 6}}

```
Reduce[a == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 0
```

> x == -2 || x == 6

To constrain `x` to the interval $[-2,2]$:

```
Solve[{a == 0, -2 <= x <= 2}, x]
```

> {{x -> -2}}

Answer (score 1):

Its a issues with your syntax, you need to make `a` a function.

```
a[x_] := -0.0154213 Sin[Pi/4 + Pi/8*x]
Solve[a[x] == 0, x]
(*{{x -> -2.}}
```

Now if you plot the function you see it has three zeroes you can use `FindRoot` and a plot to get exact values.

[image]

```
FindRoot[a[x], {x, 0}]
FindRoot[a[x], {x, -10}]
FindRoot[a[x], {x, 5}]
 (*{x -> -2.}
   {x -> -10.}
   {x -> 6.}*)
```